# How to add a page in a cordova application

Tags: html, cordova

this is probably the most noob question i have ever asked, i need to create a mobile  application for my company, i have started with using Cordova 1.9, and developing in visual studio express edition for windows phone. for those who don't know this only uses html5,CSS,javascript, and some jquerymobile for the look and feel. i have googled my hair out, and yet no answer so maybe here i can get it!

How do i add a html page to a cordova app? after i press a button it should go to a new page and  well go from there. if there is another way to iniciate a new page please help, even if it is with links to another site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do this simply by JQM button? E.g `<a href="page.html" data-role="button">Button</a>`
Or with
 `$.mobile.changePage( "page.html", { transition: "slideup"} );`

Comment: that looks like it can work but where would i get the _"page.html"_? all i have is index.html, and i cant add another html page?

Comment: Make this clear: You can't add another html page to your project? Like new-> file and add page.html

Comment: Well i found the problem... what i did was adding a .XML file en then converted it to an HTML file using _<!DOCTYPE html>_ and then referenced it using the JQM button you purposed. thanks allot this helped me allot!

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify what you mean by adding a page?

jQuery Mobile works in a way that it intercepts your HTML links and navigates to those pages via AJAX. You should be able to load external pages this way as well - the only thing you need to set is [`$.support.cors`](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html), so you can to Cross-Domain requests to those pages.

Comment: _i am very new to this, and well web apps in general, like lets say i make a windows forms app, to add a new form you simply click add new item and select windows form, now in this application i want to do the same thing, cause all i have now is a log in main page, but i dont have another page to reference as i click the log in button_ do i make an external html page and load it like you said? i am very confused about this...

Comment: this sounds like you're querying some external PHP/ASP page to process your form? do you usually code web applications, or are you completely new to this concept?

Comment: this is my 1st major web/mobile application, and i am using cordova/phonegap to achieve this? i have done asp.net app's wich is easy, so i am not unfamiliar to the .net concept, it is just i am new to mobile web development.

Comment: in that case, your question is probably too broad to be answered in a single response on StackOverflow... perhaps it would be best if you tried to search on Google for some examples and manuals how to start with jQuery Mobile and mobile web apps

Comment: i have, so this is my last resort... i never ask a question befor thoroughly going through a google session